# JSON Syntax and Errors

Tags: javascript, json

So here is my current code:

```
var training = {
"onlineCourses": [
    {
        "name":"Udacity"
        "subjects":["HTML","CSS","JS","Python"]
        "nanodegrees":["Intro to Programming","Front-End Web Developer"]
    }
],
"certifications": [
    {
        "company":"Cisco"
        "name":"Certified Certified Network Associate (CCNA)"
        "subject":"Routing and Networking"
    },
    {
        "company":"CompTIA"
        "name":["A+","Network+"]
        "subject":["General IT","Routing and Networking"]
    }
]
}
```

Which produces this error in JSONLint:

> ```
> Error: Parse error on line 3:
> ..."name": "Udacity"  "subjects": ["HTML",
> ----------------------^
> Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'STRING'
> ```

Secondly, in the class I'm taking where I need this code, they example they give implies I should write the code like this instead:

```
var training = {
    "onlineCourses": [
        {
            "name":"Udacity"
            "subjects":["HTML","CSS","JS","Python"]
            "nanodegrees":["Intro to Programming","Front-End Web Developer"]
        }
    ]
},
    "certifications": [
        {
            "company":"Cisco"
            "name":"Certified Certified Network Associate (CCNA)"
            "subject":"Routing and Networking"
        },
        {
            "company":"CompTIA"
            "name":["A+","Network+"]
            "subject":["General IT","Routing and Networking"]
        }
    ]
```

Notice that the very first { is closed after the onlineCourses array and the certifications array is not inside any set of {}s. This doesn't seem right to me and I just figured that they made a typo in the class. Am I correct on that?

Either way I get the same error:

> ```
> Error: Parse error on line 3:
> ..."name": "Udacity"  "subjects": ["HTML",
> ----------------------^
> Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'STRING'
> ```

Comment: You are missing `,` after each `key`:`value`

Answer (score 0):

Seperate each key value pairs with comma ( , )

```
{
    "name":"Udacity",
    "subjects":["HTML","CSS","JS","Python"],
    "nanodegrees":["Intro to Programming","Front-End Web Developer"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign multiple properties in an object, A comma (`,`) is needed to separate each property. Here's a proper way of your `training` variable.

```
var training = {
    "onlineCourses": [
        {
            "name":"Udacity",
            "subjects":["HTML","CSS","JS","Python"],
            "nanodegrees":["Intro to Programming","Front-End Web Developer"]
        }
    ],
    "certifications": [
        {
            "company":"Cisco",
            "name":"Certified Certified Network Associate (CCNA)",
            "subject":"Routing and Networking"
        },
        {
            "company":" CompTIA",
            "name": ["A+", "Network+"],
            "subject": ["General IT","Routing and Networking"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should have commas after each key-value pair (except the last in a set):

```
var training = {
  "onlineCourses": [
    {
      "name": "Udacity",
      "subjects": [
        "HTML",
        "CSS",
        "JS",
        "Python"
      ],
      "nanodegrees": [
        "Intro to Programming",
        "Front-End Web Developer"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "certifications": [
    {
      "company": "Cisco",
      "name": "Certified Certified Network Associate (CCNA)",
      "subject": "Routing and Networking"
    },
    {
      "company": "CompTIA",
      "name": [
        "A+",
        "Network+"
      ],
      "subject": [
        "General IT",
        "Routing and Networking"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid. You may always want to validate the JSON using validators such as http://jsonlint.com/

Here is the corrected JSON:

```
var training = {
    "onlineCourses": [{
        "name": "Udacity",
        "subjects": ["HTML", "CSS", "JS", "Python"],
        "nanodegrees": ["Intro to Programming", "Front-End Web Developer"]
    }],
    "certifications": [{
        "company": "Cisco",
        "name": "Certified Certified Network Associate (CCNA)",
        "subject": "Routing and Networking"
    }, {
        "company": "CompTIA",
        "name": ["A+", "Network+"],
        "subject": ["General IT", "Routing and Networking"]
    }]
}
```

Also, to answer the second part of the question, your JSON looks invalid as well. But, ***Secondly, in the class I'm taking where I need this code, they example they give implies I should write the code like this instead:*** isn;t that clear to conclude anything on the format.

Answer (score 0):

please make json comma (,) separate for valid syntax.
example.

```
{
   "name":"Udacity",
   "subjects":["HTML","CSS"],
   "nanodegrees":["Intro to Programming","Front-End Web Developer"]
}
```